# CKEditor 4 Display PHP Code as normal text?

Tags: php, ckeditor

Is is possible to display php code in the editor?

Currently it get's hidden by the editor, only `Title:` is visible:

```
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:left; width:200px">Title: <!--?=$row["Title"];?--></td>
```

But i want to see the php code as an normal text like, `Title: < ?=$row["Title"];?>`

```
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:left; width:200px">Title: <?=$row["Title"];?></td>
```

Comment: so you want to display exactly the string `Title: <?=$row["Title"];?>` correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to display exactly the string: `Title: <?=$row["Title"];?>`

Then you might need to escape the `<` and `>` characters:

```
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:left; width:200px">Title: &lt;?=$row["Title"];?&gt;</td>
```

This will force show the `<` and `>` characters and prevent PHP from executing the code.